# How to add seekbar Plus rewind and fast forward buttons to my media player

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

Hey guys working on a media player for my android device but not sure how to get the seekbar working and also i want to be able to fast forward and rewind by holding down the the buttons instead of pressing once

here's what i have so far

`MyMediaPlayerActivity` class:

```
     package com.technegames.mymediaplayer;

     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileDescriptor;
     import java.io.FileInputStream;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Random;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
     import android.content.res.AssetManager;
     import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
     import android.media.AudioManager;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.os.Environment;
     import android.os.PowerManager;
     import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuItem;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.Window;
     import android.view.WindowManager;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.ImageView;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     public class MyMediaPlayerActivity extends Activity {
 WakeLock wakeLock;
 private static final String[] EXTENSIONS = { ".mp3", ".mid", ".wav", ".ogg",         ".mp4" }; //Playable Extensions

List<String> trackNames; //Playable Track Titles

List<String> trackArtworks; //Track artwork names

AssetManager assets; //Assets (Compiled with APK)

File path; //directory where music is loaded from on SD Card

File path2; //directory where album artwork is loaded from on SD Card

Music track; //currently loaded track

ImageView bg; //Track artwork

Button btnPlay; //The play button will need to change from 'play' to 'pause', so we need an instance of it

Random random; //used for shuffle

boolean shuffle; //is shuffle mode on?

boolean isTuning; //is user currently jammin out, if so automatically start playing the next track

int currentTrack; //index of current track selected

int type; //0 for loading from assets, 1 for loading from SD card

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "Lexiconda");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initialize(0);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    wakeLock.acquire();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    wakeLock.release();
    if(track != null){
        if(track.isPlaying()){
            track.pause();
            isTuning = false;
            btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
        if(isFinishing()){
            track.dispose();
            finish();
        }
    } else{
        if(isFinishing()){
            finish();
        }
    }
}

private void initialize(int type){
    bg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg);
    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
    trackNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    trackArtworks = new ArrayList<String>();
    assets = getAssets();
    currentTrack = 0;
    shuffle = false;
    isTuning = false;
    random = new Random();
    this.type = type;

    addTracks(getTracks());
    loadTrack();
}

//Generate a String Array that represents all of the files found
private String[] getTracks(){
    if(type == 0){
        try {
            String[] temp = getAssets().list("");
            return temp;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if(type == 1){
        if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) 
                || Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)){
            path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            path2 = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String[] temp = path.list();
            return temp;
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SD Card is either mounted elsewhere or is unusable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//Adds the playable files to the trackNames List
private void addTracks(String[] temp){
    if(temp != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            //Only accept files that have one of the extensions in the EXTENSIONS array
            if(trackChecker(temp[i])){
                trackNames.add(temp[i]);
                trackArtworks.add(temp[i].substring(0, temp[i].length()-4));
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loaded " + Integer.toString(trackNames.size()) + " Tracks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//Checks to make sure that the track to be loaded has a correct extenson
private boolean trackChecker(String trackToTest){
    for(int j = 0; j < EXTENSIONS.length; j++){
        if(trackToTest.contains(EXTENSIONS[j])){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//Loads the track by calling loadMusic
private void loadTrack(){
    if(track != null){
        track.dispose();
    }
    if(trackNames.size() > 0){
        track = loadMusic(type);
        setImage("drawable/" + trackArtworks.get(currentTrack));
    }
}

//loads a Music instance using either a built in asset or an external resource
private Music loadMusic(int type){
    switch(type){
    case 0:
        try{
            AssetFileDescriptor assetDescriptor = assets.openFd(trackNames.get(currentTrack));
            return new Music(assetDescriptor);
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error Loading " + trackNames.get(currentTrack), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    case 1:
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path, trackNames.get(currentTrack)));
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = fis.getFD();
            return new Music(fileDescriptor);
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error Loading " + trackNames.get(currentTrack), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

//Sets the background image to match the track currently playing or a default image
private void setImage(String name) {
    if(type == 0){
        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(name, null, getPackageName());
        if(imageResource != 0){
            Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
            bg.setImageDrawable(image);
        } else{
            int defaultImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/defaultbg", null, getPackageName());
            if(defaultImageResource != 0){
                Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(defaultImageResource);
                bg.setImageDrawable(image);
            }
        }
    } else if(type == 1){
        if(new File(path2.getAbsolutePath(), trackArtworks.get(currentTrack) + ".jpg").exists()){
            bg.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path2.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + trackArtworks.get(currentTrack) + ".jpg"));
        } else{
            int defaultImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/defaultbg", null, getPackageName());
            if(defaultImageResource != 0){
                Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(defaultImageResource);
                bg.setImageDrawable(image);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    createMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case 0:
        //Set Looping
        synchronized(this){
            if(track.isLooping()){
                track.setLooping(false);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Playing Tracks Sequentially", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                track.setLooping(true);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Looping " + trackNames.get(currentTrack), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return true;
    case 1:
        //Set Shuffle
        synchronized(this){
            if(shuffle){
                setShuffle(false);
            } else{
                setShuffle(true);
            }
        }
        return true;
    case 2:
        //Stop Music
        synchronized(this){
            track.switchTracks();
            btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
        return true;
    case 3:
        //Change Source from Assets to SD Card and vice versa
        synchronized(this){
            type++;
            if(type > 1){
                type = 0;
            }
        }
        if(type == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading Tracks from Assets ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(type == 1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading Tracks from SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        initialize(type);
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

private void createMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuItem miLooping = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Looping");{
        miLooping.setIcon(R.drawable.looping);
    }
    MenuItem miShuffle = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Shuffle");{
        miShuffle.setIcon(R.drawable.shuffle);
    }
    MenuItem miStop = menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Stop");{
        miStop.setIcon(R.drawable.stop);
    }
    MenuItem miSource = menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Source");{
        miSource.setIcon(R.drawable.source);
    }
}

public void click(View view){
    int id = view.getId();
    switch(id){
    case R.id.btnPlay:
        synchronized(this){
            if(isTuning){
                isTuning = false;
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                track.pause();
            } else{
                isTuning = true;
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                playTrack();
            }
        }
        return;
    case R.id.btnPrevious:
        setTrack(0);
        loadTrack();
        playTrack();
        return;
    case R.id.btnNext:
        setTrack(1);
        loadTrack();
        playTrack();
        return;
    default:
        return;
    }
}

private void setTrack(int direction){
    if(direction == 0){
        currentTrack--;
        if(currentTrack < 0){
            currentTrack = trackNames.size()-1;
        }
    } else if(direction == 1){
        currentTrack++;
        if(currentTrack > trackNames.size()-1){
            currentTrack = 0;
        }
    }
    if(shuffle){
        int temp = random.nextInt(trackNames.size());
        while(true){
            if(temp != currentTrack){
                currentTrack = temp;
                break;
            }
            temp++;
            if(temp > trackNames.size()-1){
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Plays the Track
private void playTrack(){
    if(isTuning && track != null){
        track.play();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Playing " + trackNames.get(currentTrack).substring(0, trackNames.get(currentTrack).length()-4), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//Simply sets shuffle to isShuffle and then displays a message for confirmation
private void setShuffle(boolean isShuffle) {
    shuffle = isShuffle;
    if(shuffle){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Shuffle On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Shuffle Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

`Music` class:

```
    import java.io.FileDescriptor;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;

    public class Music implements OnCompletionListener{
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
boolean isPrepared = false;

public Music(AssetFileDescriptor assetDescriptor){
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try{
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), assetDescriptor.getStartOffset(), assetDescriptor.getLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        isPrepared = true;
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load music, uh oh!");
    }
}

public Music(FileDescriptor fileDescriptor){
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try{
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        isPrepared = true;
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load music, uh oh!");
    }
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    synchronized(this){
        isPrepared = false;
    }
}

public void play() {
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        return;
    }
    try{
        synchronized(this){
            if(!isPrepared){
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stop() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    synchronized(this){
        isPrepared = false;
    }
}

public void switchTracks(){
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

public void pause() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public boolean isLooping() {
    return mediaPlayer.isLooping();
}

public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(isLooping);
}

public void setVolume(float volumeLeft, float volumeRight) {
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeLeft, volumeRight);
}

public void dispose() {
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        stop();
    }
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
}
```

Answer (score 10):

*I hope this will help you. This Code is used in our project*

```
public class MusicPlayer extends Activity
    implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnBackward;
private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
private ImageButton btnRepeat;
private ImageButton btnShuffle;
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
// Media Player
private MediaPlayer mp;
// Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private SongsManager songManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int currentSongIndex = 0;
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    // All player buttons
    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
    btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

    // Mediaplayer
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    songManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();

    // Listeners
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

    // Getting all songs list
    songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

    // By default play first song
    playSong(0);

    /**
     * Play button click event plays a song and changes button to pause
     * image pauses a song and changes button to play image
     * */
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.pause();
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            } else {
                // Resume song
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    btnForward.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // get current song position
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()) {
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            } else {
                // forward to end position
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    /**
     * Forward button click event Forwards song specified seconds
     * */
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position
            // check if next song is there or not
            if (currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)) {
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            } else {
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    btnBackward.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
            if (currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0) {
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
            } else {
                // backward to starting position
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    /**
     * Backward button click event Backward song to specified seconds
     * */
    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (currentSongIndex > 0) {
                playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
            } else {
                // play last song
                playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Repeat button Enables repeat flag to true
     * */
    btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (isRepeat) {
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            } else {
                // make repeat to true
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isShuffle = false;
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Shuffle button Enables shuffle flag to true
     * */
    btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (isShuffle) {
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            } else {
                // make repeat to true
                isShuffle = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isRepeat = false;
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Play list click event Launches list activity
     * which displays list of songs
     * */
    btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PlayListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Receiving song index from playlist view and play the song
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
        // play selected song
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}

/**
 * Function to play a song
 * 
 * @param songIndex
 *            - index of song
 * */
public void playSong(int songIndex) {
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        mp.release();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

        // Displaying Total Duration time
        songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""
                + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        // Displaying time completed playing
        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""
                + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration,
                totalDuration));
        // System.out.println("Progress : "+progress);
        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

/**
 * 
 * */
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromTouch) {

}

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(),
            totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

/**
 * On Song Playing completed if repeat is ON play same song again if shuffle
 * is ON play random song
 * */
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    // check for repeat is ON or OFF
    if (isRepeat) {
        // repeat is on play same song again
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else if (isShuffle) {
        // shuffle is on - play a random song
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else {
        // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
        if (currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)) {
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        } else {
            // play first song
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
}
```

}